# Sonata is not working well in production mode

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm using sonata adminBundle for my project and every thing is fine in localhost but when I host the application on the remote server, only the dev mode is response as expected when I want to delete a row of a childe in m-1 relation in production mode or when I want to display the rows of the parent, I still get an error 500 I don't know what is wrong. I cannot enjoy my application in production mode at all

Answer (score 0):

Often with these kind of problems you should empty your cache and install your assets in de production environment:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#d-clear-your-symfony-cache

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#e-dump-your-assetic-assets

Also when you get a 500 it is important to check your apache and php logs as well as your symfony2 logs in /app/logs/prod.log for any errors.